# Include final result with Cucumber report

Tags: java, maven, automation, cucumber-jvm

So I'm using Cucumber JVM feature file with something like this:

```
Feature: Sign up and get confirmation
Scenario: Successfully signed up
 Given I navigate to website
 When  I fill out form
 Then  I get confirmation number
```

When I ran my tests, they all passed but I want to output the confirmation number with the result as well. Let's say I sign up for the form and the confirmation coming back is 12345, I would like to output this number with my result (preferably HTML), how do i go around to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your runner class, you can specify cucumber to output a html report like this:

```
@CucumberOptions(plugin = "html:path/to/target"})
```

Then you can use the @after tag and inject the running scenario in there like:

```
@After
public void attachScreenshotToReport(Scenario scenario) {
    byte[] screenshot = ((RemoteWebDriver) webDriverInstance).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
    scenario.write("\n");
    scenario.embed(screenshot, "image/png"); 
}
```

this method is attaching a screenshot to the html report after each scenario.
you can write any info in the scenario with:

```
scenario.write("some text")
```